# String can not be converted to a DateTime with ParseExact method

Tags: date, datetime

I have a string `7/24/2013 6:05:00 PM` and want to convert it to a `DateTime` object. 
I am using

> DateTime newDate   = DateTime.ParseExact(date,"M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt",
>   System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

but the newDate object is being `09.07.2013 06:45:00`. I want it as it is seen above the string version.

Do you have any idea why it is not converted the format I wanted or any opinion would be great how I can render it as a datetime object.

Thank you

Comment: the date string is 7/13/2013 6:05:00 PM

Comment: To be honest parsing with both InvariantCulture and CurrentCulture work for me. If you can control the datetime format you can always put it in international format and then use a standard DateTime.Parse()

E.g. YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

Comment: If you drill down the new dates properties can you confirm the values of day and month? Perhaps your display formatting style differs from the style you are trying to parse.

Comment: day is 9 and month is 7 and the other properties are also showing the true values but the date is being seen as above which I dont want. I may try to send it to the webservice to see whether it is working or not.

Answer (score 1):

As your date is already in a common format style you should try parsing using the current UI culture, in your case en-US.

E.g.

```
DateTime.ParseExact(date,"M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

By using the InvariantCulture the parsing is ignoring all cultural clues whilst parsing your string.

For more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465121.aspx

Comment: I am getting String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. exception if I use currentculture. System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US") is also giving the same format which I don't want